# position: fixed; no funciona en un template de AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, css

Este es mi código, el **componente** lo tengo en un **template** no está en el index.html, todo lo muestra correctamente pero por alguna razón el **position: fixed;** de mi CSS no funciona, alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué?

```js
exampleApp.component('backbuttonComponent', {
    template: '<a id="back-button" ng-href="/"></a>'
  });
```

```css
#back-button {
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url("../svg/back-button.svg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-color: #3c3f41;
  z-index: 12 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* 6dp */
}
```

```html
<backbutton-component></backbutton-component>
```

Comment: El CSS funciona correctamente con este HTML: `<a id="back-button" ng-href="/"></a>`. ¿Se está generando correctamente el HTML?¿Hay errores en el resto del CSS o algún estilo que sobreescriba las propiedades del botón? Si pudieras poner un ejemplo reproduciendo el error sería más fácil buscar una solución.

Comment: Este código funciona bien. El error que tienes es otro. Quizás si aportaras más datos se pueda reproducir y darte una solución.

Comment: @devconcept Lo único que no funciona por alguna razón es el **position: fixed;** lo otro se muestra correctamente. También sucede el error si coloco la etiqueta **<a>** en el template HTML normalmente sin ningún componente ni nada de eso, pero si lo coloco en el index.html sí funciona el **position: fixed;** pero de esa forma se quedaría siempre visible, solo quiero que se muestre en ese template específicamente.

Comment: @AdrianoJosué Me parece que lo que te puede estar pasando es que otro estilo esté sobreescribiendo la propiedad `position: fixed` ya que este es compatible hasta con IE 7. Quizás tengas más de una vez la directiva y esto te traiga problemas porque en html es ilegal tener varios elementos con un mismo id. Sin un ejemplo concreto es imposible saberlo.

Answer (score -2):

Colocalo en **position:absolute** y cada vez que se haga **scroll** en la pantalla, obtené cuanto se movió con el scroll (**var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();**) y aumentale/disminuile el atributo **bottom** sumando/restando ese valor cada vez que se haga scroll en la pantalla:

```
$("#back-button").css("top", $(window).height() - 10); //Es igual que poner bottom:10px;

var topInicial = $("#back-button").offsetTop();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();//Scroll hecho desde 0 hasta la posición actual
    $("#back-button").css("top", topInicial + scroll);
});
```

Esto no es con angularJs, pero funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Tampoco me funciona tu método, no se que sucede :(